# Listening to events in unit test using Viem

Tags: hardhat, events, typescript, event-handling, viem

I want to be able to tell how many approval event were sent during my test as I cannot tell how many where sent since they are auto-approved by hardhat Running Environment.

Answer (score 1):

what I did in the end

```typescript
import ERC20ABI from "@openzeppelin/contracts/build/contracts/ERC20.json";

// [...]

it('perform a complex multi-contract operation', async function () {
  // Load the contract instance using the deployment function
  const {
    myCoolContractDeployed,
    myCoolToken
  } = await loadFixture(deploy);

  await myCoolContractDeployed.write.CoolFunct([BigInt(1)]);

  const publicClient = await hre.viem.getPublicClient();
  const logs = await  publicClient.getContractEvents({
      abi: ERC20ABI.abi,
      address: myCoolToken.address, // optional filter
      eventName: 'Approval', // optional filter, name taken form the ABI (erc20: Transfer, Approval)
  })
  console.log(logs);
  expect(logs.length).to.equal(1);
});
```

Comment: This sucks big time, but it works!
However, when I use it with coverage plugin the event list is empty. Any idea? I tried removing `address` and `eventName` filter and it is still empty.